# Call a function N times in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a program:

```
deleteFunction :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
deleteFunction min input = 
 if head input == min then tail input
 else head input : deleteFunction min (tail input)

readInts :: String -> [Int]
readInts input = read input :: [Int]


findMinimum :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
findMinimum element list emptyList = 
  if list == emptyList then element
  else if element > head(list)
    then findMinimum (head list) (tail list) (emptyList)
    else findMinimum element (tail list) (emptyList)


main = do 
 let emptyList = [] 
 let n = 4 
 inputList <- getLine
 let input = readInts inputList
 let min = findMinimum (head input) input emptyList
 let result = foldr (.) id (replicate (n) (deleteFunction min input))    --HERE IS THE PROBLEM
 print result
```

`readInts` is a function that converts inputList to `[Int]`. `let result = foldr (.) id (replicate (n) (deleteFunction min input))` is the line which leads to the error. `min` is the minimal element of input. `findMinimum` is the function that calculates the `min`. `deleteFunction` finds the first element of `[Int]` which is equal to `min` and deletes it from `[Int]`.
I need to use `deleteFunction` in main N times, where N may be both entered with the keyboard or defined in the code in main.
I tried iterate, replicate and a lot of other ways but every time I had troubles with parameters like this:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘b -> b’
      Expected type: [b -> b]
        Actual type: [[Int]]
```

I request help in writing code which can call the function N times.
Thank you for your attention

Comment: Prefer pattern matching to using `head` and `tail` on lists. `deleteFunction min [] = []; deleteFunction min (x:xs) = if x == min then xs else x:deleteFunction min xs`.

Comment: `findMinimum` should just have type `[Int] -> Int`. The type `Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Int` should be the type of an internally defined helper that `findMinimum` calls with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: You already asked this at [Calling a function N times in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940555/calling-a-function-n-times-in-haskell). You're not supposed to repost questions that were already closed once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write

```
let result = foldr (.) id (replicate (n) (deleteFunction min input))
```

which attempts to replicate the *result* of applying `deleteFunction min input`. You only want to replicate the *function* `deleteFunction min`, reduce that to a single function with `foldr`, then apply *that* result to `input`.

```
let result = foldr (.) id (replicate n (deleteFunction min)) input
```

Comment: And what does foldr (.) id mean here?

Comment: Like any other use of `foldr`, it repeatedly applies `(.)` to an element from its list and the result of previous applications, `id` being used at the end of the chain. `foldr (.) id [f, g, h] == f . g . h . id`.